# Change the new line delimiter in spark 2.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with a data set which has new line delimiter set as

> `^M`

and since **spark** has line delimiter as **`\n`** , I am not able to read the data . is there any way I can set the new line delimiter in spark to **`^M`**

```
19515 14ewewee,34_e2_ewe5194_670758996438b5ff5b56b237f8,44170670,divide and rule,rambo,"sasksaksksa"
19516
19517
19518 ",2019-10-10 14:24:03+0000^M
19519 145www452,34_1092_15194_67075438b5ff5b56b237f8,713220,alpha,MESG,hlo,2019-10-10 14:31:33+0000^M
```